# adding a StringList element inbetween exisiting List items in processing

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

I am currently trying to parse a `.txt` file (subtitles file) to a `.csv` table.

Example out of the file:

```
22
00:03:36,717 --> 00:03:38,344
(thunder crashing)
```

I figured using the `StringList` Type was my best choice for that and I almost got all my information ready. The only thing left is, that I want the second line with the start pos. and the end pos. to be in seperate strings, following each other, like this:

```
22
00:03:36,717
00:03:38,344
(thunder crashing)
```

I already know how to do it with the `substring()` method, but I can't figure out how to add the new String at a specific index. the `set` function overwrites it and the `appends` function can only add it to the end of the list.

Is the use of an `ArrayList` better in hindsight? I tried doing that, but then I couldn't figure out how to use the actual element. What I have is this:

```
String s[] = loadStrings("subtest.txt");
ArrayList lines= new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
  lines.add(s[i]);
}
```

which added all the lines in seperate elements of the `ArrayList`. Now I can't access the element as a string however. If I want to get the length of a specific element, it tells me that the `length()` function doesn't exist and I can't save the element as a string either.

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Do you not know how to use an Arraylist? `lines.get(0).length()` will get the length of the first string... You have to get the string elements out of the list... There also is an add method of the Arraylist class that allows you to specify a position at which to insert a value.

Comment: And `lines.set(0, "first"  + lines.get(0))` will update the first position... However, it's not really clear what output you're expecting or why you need the list if you already have the array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, by default, `ArrayList` contains a list of `Object`s rather than a list of `String`s, so the objects you get out of it will be of the wrong data type. Because the result of `ArrayList.get()` is an `Object`, you can't assign it to a `String` or call methods of the `String` class on it (such `String.length()`).

What you want are [type generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Because ArrayList is a generic class, you can use the generics syntax to specify the type of objects it should hold:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(); //creates a list of Strings
```

Processing provides a more complete example in their [documentation of the ArrayList class](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score -1):

Considering the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you probably need to replace `" --> "` with a new line, like this:

## MainP:

```
public static void main ( String [ ] args ) throws IOException
    {
        Path path = Paths.get("yourFilePath.txt");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.replaceAll(" --> ", "\n");
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

    }
```

## Input:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,567
Anteriormente en Vikings...

2
00:00:01,765 --> 00:00:03,298
Voy a ir de nuevo a saquear Inglaterra,

3
00:00:03,300 --> 00:00:05,233
para la venganza de la
destrucción del asentamiento.
```

## Output:

```
1
00:00:00,000
00:00:01,567
Anteriormente en Vikings...

2
00:00:01,765
00:00:03,298
Voy a ir de nuevo a saquear Inglaterra,

3
00:00:03,300
00:00:05,233
para la venganza de la
destrucción del asentamiento.
```

**Note:** This way you are overwriting the input file.